# How to show all decimal digits in an Excel cell programatically using VBA

Tags: excel, number-formatting, vba

I have an Excel macro which stores some business values.

For one of the cell the value should display 999.999999 but it shows 1000 and in formula bar i see the value shown as 999.999999. Since these are converted values from one type to another, the customer wants me to show the value as it is without the decimal places getting rounded.

One workaround i thought was to convert the cell into text format before populating the value but this doesn't work as i need to support this in various regional settings.

Any suggestions on how to get the Excel VBA to know the number of digits after decimal to be displayed will be a great help.

Current code to populate cell value :

Range.Offset(0,0).Value = Response

Here, Response is the converted value i.e 999.999999 in string format.

Comment: try this:  Range.Offset(0,0).Value = CDbl(Response)   otherwise, maybe you can declare response as double instead of a string

Comment: i have tried that but that always returns me 0.00 and doesn't help much. Also, the response variable gets its value from a utility tool which returns a string value, i am not sure if converting from string to double in Excel VBA would help.

Comment: try to use the range.numberformat = "@" prior to setting the value.  make sure to include the same offset parameters so you are formatting the correct cell

Comment: I have tried that, this just converts the cell into text format but the issue here is with the regional settings for e.g. 1,000 is represented as 1.000 in German settings, so if i convert the cell to text then even in German regional settings the value will be displayed as 1,000 instead of 1.000.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be a check for the # of decimals like:

```
Dim str As String
str = Response

If Len(str) - InStr(str, ".") > 2 Then
  Range.Offset(0, 0).Value = "'" & str
Else
  Range.Offset(0, 0).Value = str
End If
```

---

Or simply do always the `Range.Offset(0, 0).Value = "'" & Response` to see the whole number ;)

---

Another way is the change of the number format like:

```
Dim str As String, x As Byte
str = Response
x = Len(str) - InStr(str, ".")
Range.Offset(0, 0).Value = str

If x < 2 Then x = 2
Range.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = "0." & Application.Rept("0", x)
```

---

**EDIT:**
For the localization you can use `Application.DecimalSeparator` to get the right one like:

```
Range.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = "0" & Application.DecimalSeparator & Application.Rept("0", x)
```

Also a change later on can be done like

```
If Len(Range.Offset(0, 0).Text) - Len(Range.Offset(0, 0).Value) Then
  Range.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = "0" & Application.DecimalSeparator & Application.Rept("0", x)
End If
```

**Edit 2:**
For automatic cell fomating, you can use the approach from Ron and directly set the cells number format to

```
0.0###############
```

Only using `#` will lead to `3` shown as `3.` and `0.3` to be `.3`. Also if changing to a location which uses `,` as separator should change the number format automatically.

Comment: Hi Dirk, I have tried this approach and it seems to be working for some of the cases. The issue which i am currently facing is with overwriting the Number format for different cell. For e.g. If i have a cell value of 1000 then the Number format is set to 0,00 and when i try  entering value like 1234.789456 then it only populates 1234,79 as the number format still shows 0,00. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @ManishAgarwal for automatic format change you can use the approach from Ron. Just see my edit and tell if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: What are your thoughts on FormatNumber function in VBA.  Can i not use it like this  Range.Offset(0, 0).Value = FormatNumber(lstrResponse, lintDecimalLength, , , Tristate.TristateTrue)

Comment: @ManishAgarwal I'm not sure what you want anymore. You want to set the formatting, but changing the number later also should work. But setting the formatting directly is no option. Just looking at your question, the answer from Ron does all you asked for...

Comment: I have been using this all this while   Range.NumberFormat = "#" + lstrDecimalSeparator + "##############" but everytime the number format returned is "#,##0.00" as a result i only get values with two decimal places which takes me back to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since Excel's precision is limited to a maximum of 15 decimal digits, you can merely custom format the cells as

```
#.###############
```

(15 #'s after the decimal)

You can do this without VBA, but the VBA code might look like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowAllDecimals()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range, C As Range

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each C In R
    If IsNumeric(C) Then _
        C.NumberFormat = "#.################"
Next C

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help if you have not found the answer.
format the target cells with .numberformat 
then use a variable type double to accept value from the calculated cells before send it to target cells.

Answer (score 0):

In short, below format code keeps all original value to decimal format.

```
0.0###############
```

I tested and it worked well with both leading zero number (0.xxx)